# Where does CucumberTestCase belong?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I'm trying to follow [Android BDD with Cucumber and Espresso — the full guide](https://medium.com/gumtree-dev-team/android-bdd-with-cucumber-and-espresso-the-full-guide-9c20cfcb8535) but I'm getting the error:

> "No tests found."

I can see in the logs that the `CucumberTestRunner` got invoked successfully.  So it seems like Cucumber can't find its own test cases.  I think my .feature files are in the right place, so that only leaves `CucumberTestCase` which could be misplaced.  The tutorial puts it in a packaged called `com.sniper.bdd.test`.

Where does `CucumberTestCase` belong?

Comment: I was facing the same error. Adding this line in gradle.build `testApplicationId "com.sniper.bdd.test"` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get Cucumber to find the tests by putting `CucumberTestCase` in the package [`<package name from AndroidManifest>.test`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-android).

So in the tutorial I guess it should have been in `com.sniper.test` not `com.sniper.bdd.test`.